# What comes after vocal warm ups and Exercises?

Tags: voice, practice, vocal-range, vocal-cords

AKA How do I actually learn to sing songs?

After I've done all my vocal/warmups practice etc then what?
Do I just attempt to go sing something?

How do I know I'm even singing that thing I'm attempting correctly?
How do I know I've gotten better at it if I'm not?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to find a good singer and sing along with them.

Maybe join a choir at church, if you go to one.

Other than that, find recordings of great singers and try to duplicate what you hear them do.